# Link bank to GDAX account?

Tags: coinbase, gdax

I just finished the GDAX account setup. Now I need to deposit fund. I clicked the button, the web page was redirected to Coinbase web site.

Then there are two options.

1. Link Bank
2. Wire transfer

Because I only want to deposit $200 for initial trial, so I select "**Link Bank**"

My question is that is there a transfer fee for that? I heard that GDAX is free but the operation is linked to Coinbase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bank deposit to either GDAX or Coinbase is completely free and takes around 7 days to complete.

Comment: One following question. I saw my coinbase account CASH(USD)  now is $200. But on the left top of GDAX balance USD is still 0. Is it normal? Do I have to transfer fund from coinbase to gdax manually?

Comment: Assuming you initiated the transfer from Coinbase, then yes you will need to go into GDAX and import your cash amount from Coinbase to GDAX. This is totally free, and nearly instant. You can avoid this next time by initiating the bank deposit in GDAX.